# How do I get data from a div in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python script that should return a text from a div.
The html looks like this:

```
<div id="bodyContent" class="vector-body">
    <div id="siteSub" class="noprint">From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</div>
```

So my script should return: "From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia", but it returns nothing

```
source = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Osaka_building_fire").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one("div[class*=noprint]").text)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `class*=noprint` What is the purpose of the asterisk?

Comment: If you use something like `soup.select('div', {'class': 'noprint'})` you'll find that it's the 7th matching `div` that has the text you need, `select_one` gets you the first, which is indeed empty.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there's other div.noprint's in the page, and the 'one' it caught is empty

An alternative is to find out, by id:

```
print(soup.select_one("div[id*=siteSub]").text)
```